# First Person Shooter box collider problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a FPS game and I have the following issue:

Sometimes, when I shoot at the enemies the hit is not recognized, even if the player is shooting in front of them. However, when they attack the player, the hit is recognized normally.

They have a box collider and a rigidbody attached to them.

This script is attached to the player:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DisparaArma : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GerenciaArma gerenciaArma;

    public float nDisparo = 15f;
    private float TempoProximoDisparo;
    public float damage = 20f;

    private Animator ZoomCameraIn;
    private bool zoomed;

    private Camera Maincamera;
    private GameObject mira;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        gerenciaArma = GetComponent<GerenciaArma>();
        ZoomCameraIn = transform.Find(Tags.LOOK_ROOT).transform.Find(Tags.ZOOM_CAMERA).GetComponent<Animator>();

        mira = GameObject.FindWithTag(Tags.MIRA);
        Maincamera = Camera.main;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Atira();
        ZoomInAndOut();
    }

    void Atira()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if(gerenciaArma.SelecionaArma().tipoBala == WeaponBulletType.BULLET)
            {
                gerenciaArma.SelecionaArma().AnimacaoTiro();
                DisparaBala();


            }

        }
    }

    void ZoomInAndOut()
    {
        if (gerenciaArma.SelecionaArma().mira_tipo == TipoMira.AIM)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
            {
                ZoomCameraIn.Play(Animacoes.ZOOM_IN_ANIM);
               // gerenciaArma.SelecionaArma().Aim(true);
                mira.SetActive(false);
                print("VaiZoom");
            }

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))//
            {
                ZoomCameraIn.Play(Animacoes.ZOOM_OUT_ANIM);
                //gerenciaArma.SelecionaArma().Aim(false);
                mira.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
    }

    void DisparaBala()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(Maincamera.transform.position, Maincamera.transform.forward, out hit))
        {

            if (hit.transform.tag == Tags.ENEMY_TAG)
            {
                hit.transform.GetComponent<ScriptVida>().DanoAplicado(damage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this one is attached to the enemies:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class ScriptVida : MonoBehaviour
{
    private IndioAnimações indio_Anim;
    private NavMeshAgent navAgent;
    private IndioController indio_Controller;

    public float vida = 100f;
    public bool is_Player, is_Cannibal, is_Tiger;

    private bool morto;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        if (is_Tiger || is_Cannibal)
        {
            indio_Anim = GetComponent<IndioAnimações>();
            indio_Controller = GetComponent<IndioController>();
            navAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        }

        if (is_Player)
        {

        }
    }

    public void DanoAplicado(float damage)
    {
        if (morto)
            return;
        vida -= damage;


        if (is_Player)
        {

        }

        if (is_Tiger || is_Cannibal)
        {
            if (indio_Controller.EnemyState == EnemyState.PATROL)
            {
                indio_Controller.chase_Distance = 50f;
            }
        }

        if (vida <= 0)
        {
            JogadorMorre();
            morto = true;
            print(vida);
        }

    }

    void JogadorMorre()
    {
        if (is_Cannibal)//
        {
            GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;
            GetComponent<BoxCollider>().isTrigger = false;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(-transform.forward * 50f);

            indio_Controller.enabled = false;
            navAgent.enabled = false;
            indio_Anim.enabled = false;
        }

        if (is_Tiger)
        {
            GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;
            GetComponent<BoxCollider>().isTrigger = false;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(-transform.forward * 50f);

            indio_Controller.enabled = false;
            navAgent.enabled = false;
            indio_Anim.enabled = false;
        }

        if (is_Player)
        {
            GameObject[] enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(Tags.ENEMY_TAG);
            for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Length; i++)
            {
                enemies[i].GetComponent<IndioController>().enabled = false;
            }

            GetComponent<Movimentação>().enabled = false;
            GetComponent<DisparaArma>().enabled = false;
            GetComponent<GerenciaArma>().SelecionaArma().gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        if (tag == Tags.PLAYER_TAG)
        {
            Invoke("RestartGame", 3f);
        }

        else
        {
            Invoke("TurnOffGameObject", 3f);
        }
    }

    void RestartGame()
    {
        UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene("Gameplay");
    }

    void TurnOffGameObject()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

}
```

I think the problem is related to the box collider.
How could I solve this guys?

Comment: It's not because of boxcollider %99 percent. If you can hit after they attack to Player, I'm suspicious about those lines: 

`if (hit.transform.tag == Tags.ENEMY_TAG)
            {
                hit.transform.GetComponent<ScriptVida>().DanoAplicado(damage);
            }`

Are you sure that enemies have ENEMY_TAG before attack? Maybe it's because they don't have ENEMY_TAG yet?

Comment: They have "Enemy" as tag man. I can hit them before they attack the player. The hit is just recognized if I shoot at in the middle of their bodies. I don't know man, but I still think is something related to the box collider, because I can "pass" through them. https://youtu.be/mfS86PWUmAc

Comment: If your bullets are very fast, they could go through the collider between two calls of FixedUpdate, so no registeration. Try changing the detection type (not discrete as it's very slow). If that still does not work, you should instead of looking for collisions, use raycast when you shoot and simulate the hit

Comment: Hi man, I use raycast in these lines: ```void DisparaBala() { RaycastHit hit; if(Physics.Raycast(maiCam.transform.position, maiCam.transform.forward, out hit)) { print("We hit: " + hit.transform.gameObject.tag); if (hit.transform.tag == Tags.ENEMY_TAG) { hit.transform.GetComponent<ScriptVida>().DanoAplicado(damage); } } }``` When I uncheked is trigger it works, but the enemy starts to go up.